# Perform digital modulations (HW or SW)

Tags: rf, modulation, digital-modulation

I am considering doing a project which revolves around microcontrollers (AVR, or arduino) and digital modulation to learn about digital RF.

I have simple things in mind, just for experimentation.

The problem with dsigital modulations, is that although i was taught the theory at school (equations, constellation diagrams) little is taught about actually implementing them.

So my question is how do you implement digital modulations?

Expecially the most intensive ones like OFDM, or OFTDM?

You use a hardware chip, or are there software libraries that run on DSP chips?

Comment: You use a hardware chip. If you want to achieve a significative distance you'll need an amplifier, that is difficult to build at high frequencies.

Comment: I wouldn't jump in at the deep end. Why not get some 433.92 MHZ receiver and transmitter modules. They cost virtually nothing and you can get your hands dirty on these first.

Answer (score 1):

There are chips out there that can perform carrier frequency modulation as well as baseband data encoding. It's not really clear to me what exactly is your objective here. If you want to build your own custom communication system, then I would wager that you probably will want some expensive equipment, like a spectrum analyzer, among others. If your goal is just to mess around with wireless digital communication and play with different modulation schemes, I might recommend something like a CC430 development kit from Texas Instruments. With this, you won't be able to see the modulation in action, but you can try different schemes and compare the relative peformance between them. You will need some programming skills to use this kit, however.

Answer (score 0):

How do you implement any other algorithm? Any sort of computing machine will work, if it has sufficient resources (and in modern times, sufficient resources are not difficult to find). Yes, there are ASICs available. There are also general purpose DSPs that can be programmed for the task. Even a general purpose computer can be programmed to do the task. There are even [libraries to make the job easier](http://gnuradio.org/). Yes, even an [iPad can do it](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/isdr/id480077371?mt=8).